# How to use the RdBu Colors with Colorbrewer Cycle with PGFplots?

Tags: pgfplots, color

I would like to use the color cycle function for my graphs. Currently I am just using `cycle list name=exotic` but I would like to change to the RdBu color set from the colorbrewer.

```
\begin{axis}[
    
ybar,
domain=0:1,
cycle list name=exotic,
every axis plot/.append style={no markers},
ylabel= NmCherry$^{+}$ Cells/mm$^{2}$,
width=\textwidth,
height=7cm,
ymax=125,
ymin=0,
xmin=-0.5,
xmax=7.5,
xticklabels={A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H},xtick={0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7},
x tick label style={rotate=90},
legend style={at={(0.77,0.82)},anchor=west}]

\addplot+[error bars/.cd,
    y dir=both,y explicit]
```

Thanks for the advice :)